# Handling default VirtualHost in Apache

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.2, httpd.conf

please correct any of my statements if I'm wrong.

I've realized that VirtualHosts are loaded through `httpd.conf` line (exact path is individual)

```
Include conf/vhosts/*.conf
```

And each `*.conf` host is loaded in order given by filename

```
0default.conf
1site.conf
2site2.conf
...
```

Is this good way to handle which site will appear on (single and only) IP address?

I mean, if I go to my server IP (`12.34.56.78`), i will see VirtualHost defined by `0default.conf`, is this right way how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way I do it, except I use a slightly different prefix which is better when you list the folder IMO:

```
000-defaultsite
001-firstsite
002-secondsite
etc...
```